# Autotest can't find growl? (Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.11)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Haven't seen any other errors like this. Autotest is complaining it can't find Growl even though it's installed. Tried uninstalling/reinstalling everything with sudo. Everything is up-to-date. This is for Mac 10.8.2.

### ZenTest is installed and up-to-date.

### Redid bundle install

### Autotest is in the gemfile

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'autotest-growl'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-fsevent'
end
```

.autotest (located in the app root directory) requires these:

```
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'
require 'autotest/fsevent'
require 'autotest/growl'

Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |autotest|
  %w{.git .svn .hg .DS_Store ._* vendor tmp log doc}.each do |exception|
  autotest.add_exception(exception)
  end
end
```

Here's the console output:

```
sample_app jameswest$ autotest

loading autotest/rails_rspec2

/Users/jameswest/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby -rrubygems -S '/Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.10.1/exe/rspec' --tty '/Users/jameswest/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb' /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in load': /Users/jameswest/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:52: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:inblock in load_spec_files' from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in each' from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:inload_spec_files' from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in run' from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:inrun' from /Users/jameswest/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Growl not found: please install Growl and try again
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [Growl App](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15979/growl) in your system.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please consider providing more detailed answer, instead of mere link.